# Finding all solutions of an expression and expressing them in the form $a+bi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$6x^2+12x+7=0$$

Steps I took:

$$\frac { -12\pm \sqrt { 12^{ 2 }-4\cdot6\cdot7 }  }{ 12 } $$

$$\frac { -12\pm \sqrt { -24 }  }{ 12 } $$

$$\frac { -12\pm i\sqrt { 24 }  }{ 12 } $$

$$\frac { -12\pm 2i\sqrt { 6 }  }{ 12 } $$

I don't know where to go from here to arrive at the correct answer...

Comment: You have arrived, just note $a=-1, b=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt6}6$.

Comment: @Macavity

The correct answer should be $\frac { -6\pm \sqrt { 6 } i }{ 6 } $

I don't see it in what I arrived at...

Comment: Divide both your numerator and denominator by $2$ if you want it in that form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost done
$$\frac { -12\pm 2i\sqrt { 6 }  }{ 12 }=\frac{-12}{12}\pm\frac{2i\sqrt6}{12}=-1\pm i\frac{\sqrt6}{6} $$

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand why the answer was listed as $\frac { -6\pm \sqrt { 6 } i }{ 6 } $ when the instructions clearly said "... in the form $a+bi$"

So would my answer have been wrong on a test?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer I would say that strictly speaking, yes, your answer is incomplete. I would remove some, but not all points from it.

Comment: Strictly following the instructions should result in "$-1+\frac{\sqrt6}6i$ and $-1+(-\frac{\sqrt6}6)i$". But only a sadist instructor would demand it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If someone answers $\frac{a+bi}{c}$ *knowing* that the form $\frac{a}{c}+\frac bci$ is only one step away, then the answer should be considered correct. If he doesn't, then points should be taken away.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac ac + \frac bc$$

Answer (score 1):

In this case $a=-1$ and $b=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$ or $b=-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$